# Smallest partition of an interval which separates given points

Tags: number-theory, set-partition

I am given a set of $M$ points in a closed interval.

I would like to partition the segment (with equidistant points), in such a way that my partition contains all these chosen points and since there are infinitely many such partitions, I want to keep the coarsest one.

Is this easy? I don't see how to do it at once.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Does segment mean a line segment? Are you partitioning your segment into smaller line segments? In any case, if you're partitioning your segment, what do you mean by your partition containing all the chosen points? Each point is part of the segment, therefore it will belong to a partition no matter how you partition the segment.

Comment: A line segment yes, a piece of line. There are $M$ points chosen a priori. Now, a posteriori I want to chop this segment into equally distant points $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ such that the $M$ chosen points a priori are one of these $t_i$. I want the coarsest partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick one end of the line segment as the starting point. Each point $x_i$ of the $M$ points is some from the start of the line segment; let $d_i$ be the ratio of the distance of $x_i$ from the start of the line segment to the total distance of the line segment. If any of the $d_i$ are not rational numbers, you cannot divide up your line segment equally in the way you want to. If they are all rational numbers, let $\frac{p_i}{q_i}$ be $d_i$ in lowest terms. Then you will want to divide up your line segment into $lcm(q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_m)$ equal pieces to get your coarsest possible partition.

Comment: God pays you with eternal life! Thanks!